# OIS GCC Compiler error

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, ogre

im trying to compile a simple Ogre3d application using OIS; i override the function like so:

```
virtual bool keyPressed(const OIS::KeyEvent& arg);
```

However, i get linker errors like this:

```
CMakeFiles/thorium.dir/Application/Application.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTVN7Thorium11ApplicationE[_ZTVN7Thorium11ApplicationE]+0x48): undefined reference to `Thorium::Application::keyPressed(OIS::KeyEvent const&)'
```

Ive added the library to my cmake as well as tried using a shared library but it also did not work. Im using the [ois](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/ois/) package and therefore havent compiled myself.

```
target_link_libraries(... OgreMain OIS.a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undefined reference error often occures when the library code not loaded.
Put libNAME.a file in lib searching path and compile modules with key
-lNAME

Comment: Don't worry, i forgot to define one of the virtual functions in my cpp file which created the error